# How does one express the English phrase "on your person" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

English has the useful expression of *on you* or *on your person*. For example, *Do you have a pen on you?* I'm not sure whether this is common usage in American parlance, but certainly in Britain it would be understood.

In other words, the person asking the above question is not asking whether someone **possesses** a pen, but whether they have one in their pocket or handbag, right there and then.

Other examples: *I keep some cash on me at all times.*
*I'm sorry, I don't have my phone on me at the moment - I left it on my desk.*

Is there a concise way of expressing this idea in Esperanto?

Comment: yes, this is common in American English

Answer (score 6):

"*Havi kun si.*"

It's the first definition in PIV. (That *kun* means the things are in the same place.)

PIV also lists *kunporti* defined as *porti kun si aŭ sur si*. *Sur* in this case mostly means clothing, so *porti kun si* is another acceptable variation, but only if the context allows it. For example, it's possible to bring something with you on a trip but leave it in a room.

- *Mi kunportis krajonojn, sed ili estas en mia ĉambro. Mi ne havas ilin kun mi nun.*
- I brought pencils, but they're in my room. I don't have them on me now.

Comment: The E-o "porti" part is congruent with English "on". + for **kunporti**.

Comment: *Kunporti* is in fact used is several contexts where we would not say "on you" in English. "*Eĉ kafopoton vi kunportas*" ... it's difficult to have a coffee pot "on you".

Answer (score 2):

I would use the preposition **ĉe** (accompaning, with).

> *I keep some cash on me at all times.*
>
> Mi ĉiam tenas iom da mono **ĉe** mi.
>
> *Do you have a pen on you?*
>
> Ĉu vi havas plumon ĉe vi?
>
> Ĉu vi disponas pri plumo?

The verb `kunhavi` / preposition `kun` would be more ambiguous, but that is just my impression.

Comment: You could also say _mi ne portas monon / plumon kun mi_, but more often than not I would prefer using  _ĉe mi_.

Comment: "Kunhavi" for sure is not correct. There's nothing wrong with "kun" though. To me "Ĉu vi havas plumon ĉe vi?" means "Do you have a pen at your place." It's the exact opposite of "on you."

Comment: @Vidamuzo **kunporti / porti kun** indeed would be my favourite. Make it a voteable answer.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander **ĉe vi** indeed can mean _at your place_ as _ĉe_ has many sences. I think Vidamuzo found a better translation.

Comment: I've edited my own answer to explain the problem with "kunporti." It's a decent choice in the right context, but not 100% the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the naive translation, *sur mi* or even just *sure*, would work much of the time.

- *Mi ĉiam tenas iom da kontanto apud mi / enpoŝe*. I always keep some cash on me.
- *Pardonon, mi ne havas mian telefonon enmane / apude / sure; mi lasis ĝin sur mia skribmeblo.* Sorry, I don't have my phone to hand / by me / on me; I left it on my desk.

I agree with Tomaso that *ĉe mi* in this context primarily means "at my house." Unless you were explicitly pointing to it, I would misunderstand.

---

- *Ĉu vi havas metalajn objektojn sur vi? sur via korpo?* Do you have metal objects on you? on your person? ("On your person" is merely a genteel way of saying "on your body.")
- *Ĉu vi havas juvelojn sur vi?* Do you have jewellery on you?
- *Ĉu vi eble havas moneron aŭ ĵetonon enpoŝe / ensake?* Do you happen to have a coin or token on you?
- *Ĉu vi havas plumon prete?* Do you have a pen ready?
- *Ĉu vi havas krajonon por tuja uzo?* Do you have a pencil you can use straight away?

Answer (score 0):

I think both *porti kun si* and *havi kun si* are good candidates for *have on you*, although the second one sounds more like *have with you*. In my opinion *kunporti* could also work, but only if it is followed by *kun si*, which sounds superfluous.

Another way to convey a similar notion is to use *porti ĉe si*, which is less context-dependent than *havi ĉe si*. This last one usually means *have at home*, unless the context shows otherwise. For example, in the sentence *ĉu vi portas krajonon ĉe vi?* it's hard to imagine that the question is about having a pen at home, rather than having it on you. Here are some examples from Tekstaro (emphasis are mine):

> - Nun venis du kaporaloj, kaj tiuj traserĉis min. Sed ili ne sukcesis. Ĉio, kion ili trovis, estis kelkaj frankoj, disŝirita naztuko, eta
>     kombilo kaj sapopeco. La sapon mi **portis ĉe mi** kvazaŭ legitimaĵo,
>     ke mi apartenas al civilizita raso, ĉar mia eksteraĵo ne ĉiam permesis
>     konkludi tion.
> - La mono, kiun Stanislav **portis ĉe si**, bela fasko da danaj kronoj, jam delonge estis trans la montoj.

Answer (score 0):

## English Answer

In English it must be a prepositional phrase describing the verbs `to have`, `to keep`, `to bring`, or `to carry`. However, you can translate it to Esperanto in several ways, depending on the context and your style.

In my opinion, I prefer not to say `ĉe mi` because that also means `at my place`, as it does in French.

Furthermore, I wouldn't use `sur mi` or `en mi` because Esperanto most often use those prepositions for something that is physically *on me* or physically *in me*.

### TL,DR;

Use `kun`-based phrases because the object (for example `the cash`) is physically *with* you and **not** physically on your body.

Examples are below.

## Esperanta Respondo

En la Angla, ĝi devas esti prepozicia frazparto, kiu preskribas la verbojn `havi`,`teni`, aŭ `porti`. Tamen, oni povas traduki ĝin al Esperanto per pluraj manieroj, kiuj dependas de la kuntexto kaj sia stilo.

Laŭ mi, mi ne preferas diri `ĉe mi` ĉar tio signifas ankaŭ `ĉe mia hejmo`, kiel en la Franca.

Plue, mi ne uzus `sur mi` nek `en mi` ĉar Esperanto plej ofte uzas tiujn prepoziciojn por io, kio estas *fizike* sur aŭ en iu.

### TL,NL; (Tro longa, ne legu)

Uzu frazpartojn per la vorto `kun` ĉar la objecto (ekzemple `la papermono`) estas fizike *kun* oni kaj **ne** fizike sur onia korpo.

Ekzemploj malsupre estas.

## Example Translations / Ekzemplaj Tradukoj

Grouped by sense / Grupigita laŭ senco

### Describing the action / Preskribanta la agon

*I don't have cash on me.*

> Mi ne havas kun mi papermonon.
>
> Mi ne kunhavas papermonon.

*I don't carry cash on me.*

> Mi ne portas kun mi papermonon.
>
> Mi ne kunportas papermonon.

*I don't keep cash on me.*

> Mi ne tenas kun mi papermonon.
>
> Mi ne kuntenas papermonon.

### Describing the object / Preskribanta la objekton

*I don't have / keep / bring / carry cash on hand.*

> Mi ne havas kuntenan / kunportan papermonon.